# Golang CSV read : extraneous " in field error

Tags: csv, go

I am using a simple program to read CSV file, somehow I noticed when I created a CSV using EXCEL or windows based computer go library fails to read it. even when I use cat command it only shows me last line on the terminal. It always results in this error `extraneous " in field`.

I researched somewhat than I found it is somewhat related to carriage return differences between OS.
But I really want to ask how to make a generic csv reader. I tried reading the same csv using `pandas` and it was reading successfully. But i am not been able to achieve this using my Go code.

[image]

Also screen shot of correct csv Is here

[image: Csv is working fine]

Comment: The carriage return doesn't matter here. Your csv has one quote too much at the end, visible in the first image, not in the second.

Comment: I corrected that wrong snapshot still throws error

Comment: changing the screenshot doesn't change the datasource. Did you make sure the CSV doesn't actually contain the extra `"` anywhere?

Comment: Yes Elias i have doubled checked this thing and this is always happening when ever i am using csv created from windows or excel. I can forward you the exact data source.

Answer (score 2):

Your file clearly shows that you've got an extra quote at the end of the content. While programs like `pandas` may be fine with that, I assume it's not valid `csv` so go does return an error.

Quick example of what's wrong with your data: https://play.golang.org/p/KBikSc1nzD

**Update**: After your update and a little bit of searching, I have to apoligize, the carriage return does matter and seems to be tha main culprit here, Go seems to be ok handling the `\r\n` windows variant but not the `\r` one. In that case what you can do is wrap the `bytes.Reader` into a custom reader that replaces the `\r` byte with the `\n` byte.

Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/vNjzwAHmtg

Please note, that the example is just that, an example, it's not handling all the possible cases where `\r` might be a legit byte.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out wrong snapshot but i have corrected snapshot this case is failing.

Comment: Ok, in that case log the error with `log.Printf("%#v", err)` that should tell you on which line and what column the undesired quote is and i'll try updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes is not there some standard set of carriage returns in standard library. like i am trying to implement some generic upload but i am blocked in this

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of the std lib, but the `encoding/csv.Reader` treats `\r` as a normal character as long as it's not followed by a `\n`, if it is then it's folded into just `\n` which is treated as a new line.. so you'll have to either look for some 3rd party csv packages that handle `\r` out of the box, or you'll have to do something like in the example i've given, where you filter the lone `\r`s, replace them with `\n`s, and then pass the bytes to the csv reader.

Comment: I had the same error when using a csvReader with a wrong `csvReader.Comma` seperator `;` instead of `,` between the rows while some rows contained `"` symbols it became one huge row with wrong amount. Just setting the correct seperator symbol fixed the issue for me.